# How to get first element on jQuery cycle?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-cycle

I want to do a vertical center on all my cycles which `height < 531`:

```
before : function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag){
    foto = $(nextSlideElement).find('img');
    alert(foto.height());
    if(foto.height() < 531){
        foto.css('margin-top', 266 - (foto.height()/2));
    }
},
```

But the alert returns me "0" on first element, adding 266px margin top no matter its size.
I already tried `before` with `currSlideElement` and `nextSlideElement`, same for `after` .

What's wrong?

Comment: most likely it just isn't loaded yet.

Comment: try using `$(el).clientHeight`

Comment: @Kevin B, You're right. Just wrapped it with `setInterval(function(){}, 1000)` and it "worked". Now I must discover how to do it when image it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `alert($(foto).height());`. Find does not return a jQuery object.

Comment: `$.fn.find` does return a jQuery object... and if that were the case, how would that explain the fact that it works for the rest of the slides, but not the first?